# unable to fetch all values from ajax GET method

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, get

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bindCity() {
    // Some javascript code
                //declare options array and populate
                var modelnames = new Array();
                $.get("file.php?mt=" + qs, function(data) {
                        eval(data);
                        if(modelnames.length > 0) {
                            addOptions(modelnames);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        function addOptions(cl) {
            //enable child select and clear current child options
            $("#mn").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#mn").html('');
            //repopulate child list with array from helper page
            var city = document.getElementById('mn');
            for(var i = 0; i < cl.length; i++) {
                city.options[i] = new Option(cl[i].text, cl[i].value);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This is the PHP script (**After getting the values to $mt**):-

```
$SQLqueryTry = "SELECT mn FROM pd WHERE pd_mt = '$mt'";
    $SQLqueryETry = mysql_query($SQLqueryTry, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($Try = mysql_fetch_array($SQLqueryETry))
    {
        $output = "modelnames.push(new Option('$Try[mn]', '$Try[mn]'));\n";
    }
```

My output code in PHP file:-

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $output;
```

Now i am able to fetch only one value when it is `$output = "modelnames.push(new Option('$Try[mn]', '$Try[mn]'));\n";`

However when i add `.` to `$output =`, to make it `$output .= "modelnames.push(new Option('$Try[mn]', '$Try[mn]'));\n";`

I am unable to get any value. What is the problem?

Comment: modelnames.push...? wats that, you're doing JS in PHP...?

Comment: Yes i am echoing that value which the above script reads:- Its here in step three, i am going through this tutorial, hope you can help, http://www.dougv.com/2009/04/24/using-ajax-to-data-bind-a-child-drop-down-list-based-on-the-selected-option-of-a-parent-select-control/

Comment: @AaronW. Still its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to see any errors in your error log?

My first guess is that you've forgotten to initialize the `$output` variable before using `.=` on it.

Maybe try:

```
$output = "";
while ($Try = mysql_fetch_array($SQLqueryETry))
{
    $output .= "modelnames.push(new Option('$Try[mn]', '$Try[mn]'));\n";
}
```

Comment: @AbhilashShukla I almost broke my head against a wall a couple of years ago trying to solve the very same problem. You're welcome. Happy coding!

Comment: Please stop recommending to write new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško There's no recommendation to *write new code*. Both the question and the answer relate to a specific error in the *existing* code. This has nothing to do with mysql_*-vs-PDO debate.